# When will the seller credit me the closing costs if agreed upon?

Tags: united-states, investing, rental-property

I've recently purchased (my first) an out of state rental property.  While going through the process, the agent told me the seller will take care of closing costs.

I've received the final closing disclose yesterday from my lender but I still see the closing cost amount listed?

Am I going to get credited this closing amount on the day of closing?

Comment: Does the lender know of this deal? do you have an agent? or does the agent you mention work for the seller? Is any of this in writing?

Comment: The closing is when everything (including closing costs) gets sorted out. Multiple checks change hands (perhaps figuratively), and everyone gets their share. The closing disclosure shows who get what. Make sure that the amount you're getting is what you expect.

Comment: Don't sign anything until they show you on paper that the seller is responsible for closing costs.  Verbal agreements mean nothing if the paperwork contradicts it.